# PHP form without opening a new window

Tags: php, forms

Good day/evening. I have this sort of form in HTML:

```
<form action="scripts/form-testimonial.php" class="form" method="post">
  <ul>
    <li><label for="name">Name</label> <input class="required" id="namef3" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text"></li>
    <li><label for="email">E-mail</label> <input class="required" id="emailf3" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" type="text"></li>
    <li><label for="company">Company</label> <input id="companyf3" name="company" placeholder="Company (if applicable)" type="text"></li>
    <li><label for="msg">Message</label> <textarea class="required" cols="43" id="msgf3" name="msg" placeholder="Your feedback" rows="8"></textarea></li>
  </ul>
  <button class="submit" type="submit">Send your feedback</button>
</form>
```

and this sort of php sript for this form as a separate file:

```
<?php
  $receip = "office@avehire.co.uk";
  $subj = "Testimonial";
  $bodymsg = "Name: ".$_POST['name']."\n"
               ."Company: ".$_POST['company']."\n"
               ."Email: ".$_POST['email']."\n"
               ."Message: ".$_POST['msg']."\n";

      if(!$_POST['msg']){
             header("Location: ../error.html");
             exit;
      }

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  if(mail($receip, $subj, $bodymsg, 'From: Contact <'.$email.'>')){
  header("Location: ../msg_sent_feedback.html"); 
  }
?>
```

I also have a validator for this form, but this is not important. What is more important here is the way how this form works. Basically - when you click submit button - it goes to a separate php file, process the form and then - from what is already there - goes to msg_sent_feedback.html file. What I want to do is to NOT opens a separate file but just display a message in the same basic html file where the actual form exists. A message e.g. "Message sent".

Another thing - if I already have a validation script - do I need to have the first "if" in this form? or can I remove it totally? the one which redirects to error.html. Or can I remove these 4 lines? That line - I guess - is responsible for errors in the form, but as I mentioned, I have a validation script. I don't really want to change html. is it possible to modify the php script to work within the html document, as instructed above? thanks

Comment: You want to look into AJAX.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use AJAX.

Comment: I have no idea about ajax and php to be honest. Just very very basic knowledge about php. Any example how can I do it? or is this more advanced process?

Comment: then wouldn't it be easier\safer to just stick with the 'standard' approach until l you learn more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an Jquery ajax example that will help you.

```
<?php
      $receip = "office@avehire.co.uk";
      $subj = "Testimonial";
      $bodymsg = "Name: ".$_POST['name']."\n"
                   ."Company: ".$_POST['company']."\n"
                   ."Email: ".$_POST['email']."\n"
                   ."Message: ".$_POST['msg']."\n";

          if(!$_POST['msg']){
                 echo "<h1>Error sending e-mail";
                 exit;
          }

      $email = $_POST['email'];
      if(mail($receip, $subj, $bodymsg, 'From: Contact <'.$email.'>')){
        echo "<h1>Email sent successfully</h1>";
      }
    ?>
```

Html :

```
<!Doctype html>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function submitmyform(){
    data=$('#myform').serialize();
        $.ajax({
        url: "myphpfile.php",
        type:'POST',
        data:data,
        async:false,
        dataType:'html',
        success: function(msg){

            $('#response_goes_here').html(msg);

        }
    });

}

</script>

    <form action="" id="myform">

        <ul>
            <li>    <label for="name">Name</label>              <input id="namef3" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="required"/>            
          </li>
            <li>    <label for="email">E-mail</label>           <input id="emailf3" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="required"/>        
          </li>
            <li>    <label for="company">Company</label>        <input id="companyf3" name="company" type="text" placeholder="Company (if applicable)" />   
          </li>
            <li>    <label for="msg">Message</label>            <textarea id="msgf3" name="msg" cols="43" rows="8" placeholder="Your feedback" class="required"></textarea> 
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="submitmyform();">Send your feedback</button>
    </form>

<div id="response_goes_here"></div>
```

Comment: thanks @fobus. Let me test it tomorrow as it's very late here. Will accept your answer if this will do the job. I'm sure it will. Thanks a lot.